# How to provide default value for positional argument while formatting string

Tags: python-2.7

Is it possible to provide default values while formatting string in python for one of its keyword argument.

Consider below example

```
MY_STRING = '{name}{age}'
print MY_STRING.format(name='sameer', age=30)
```

How will I format MY_STRING without specifying age every time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `partial`:

```
from functools import partial

MY_STRING = '{name}{age}'
format_name = partial(MY_STRING.format, age=30)
print format_name(name='sameer')
#  sameer30
```

It is possible to use `str.format` instead of `MY_STRING.format` to make this a bit more generic:

```
format_name = partial(str.format, age=30)
print format_name(MY_STRING, name='sameer')
#  sameer30
print format_name('another string with {name} and {age}', name='sameer')
# another string with sameer and 30
```